# How to allow console.log's rotation on JBOSS 7

Tags: logging, jboss, jboss7.x

I have a domain setup with 2 servers.

We have excessive logging in `/jboss/hc/console.log` (lowering the level is not an option at this point), rotating does not help as after restart Jboss keeps writting to the same file, even if it's renamed.

- logrotate test didn't work.
- [script written by me](https://github.com/alexmeise/scripts/blob/master/restart_jboss_service.sh) did not work

Could it be the "append" topic ?(it's set to true)

I have check with lsof during stop and start and there is no process using the file when I do

```
mv console.log console.log.20180000X
```

nevertheless after starting back the hc service jboss keeps writing in the renamed log.

How do I configure the logging so that the file `console.log` rotates correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely the `console.log` is a result of piping `stdout` and `stderr` to the file. There is probably another log file, e.g. `$JBOSS_HOME/domain/logs/host-conroller.log` assuming you're using a domain server, that contains the same information. I would suggest actually remove the console handler instead of attempting to rotate the `console.log`.

### Domain Instance

To remove the console handler in a domain server you need to remove the handler from the servers:

```
/profile=full/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:remove-handler(name=CONSOLE)
```

Note you'll need to execute that on each profile that is being used.

Next you'll need to need to edit the `$JBOSS_HOME/domain/configuration/logging.properties` file and remove the `CONSOLE` handler from the `logger.handlers` property.

Note you could also do this for the `$JBOSS_HOME/domain/configuration/default-server-logging.properties` too.

### Standalone Instance

For standalone it's much easier. You just need to execute the following CLI command.

```
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:remove-handler(name=CONSOLE)
```

Note that in both cases this assumes the default logging configuration. If this is not the case you'll want to ensure you have some kind of other handler attached to the root logger.

Comment: Why removing the console.log? The question asks how to rotating it, not removing it.

Comment: It's only a suggestion if `stdout` is being redirected to a log file since the same information by default would be going into the `server.log` which is already rotated.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, because the `console.log` contains some more informations that I don't find in the `server.log`, like the operations made by JBoss itself.

Comment: Nearly everything printed to the console, by default, should end up in the `server.log`. The `JBOSS_HOME` is set in the `jboss.home.dir` system property. The `JAVA_OPTS` will end up in the DEBUG log about system properties. What is it that you feel would be missing?

Comment: The following is only a simple example:
INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: JBoss EAP 7.2.4.GA (WildFly Core 6.0.16.Final-redhat-00002) starting
This one is in the console.log but not in the server.log !

Comment: It definitely is for me. Again I'm assuming the default configuration so if the logging subsystem configuration was updated, then there is definitely a chance they will not match.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to logrotate might be rotatelogs or cronolog. for example:

> > ./standalone.sh 2>&1 | /usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l /path_to/console.log.%Y-%m-%d 86400 &